# How to force NLog to overwrite the log file

Tags: .net, nlog, overwrite

I need NLog to overwrite the log file when the application is restarted.  Currently it appends to existing file.
For example I have something like this in my NLog.config

```
<targets>
  <target xsi:type="File" name="fileLog" 
          fileName="${longdate}.log" layout="${message}" />
</targets>
```

It would be nice if I was able to add to `<target>` something like this `append="false"` so instead of appending to existing log it would overwrite.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

replace your config section

```
<targets>
  <target xsi:type="File" name="fileLog" 
          fileName="${longdate}.log" layout="${message}" deleteOldFileOnStartup="true"/>
</targets>
```

Comment: deleteOldFileOnStartup works only when the "FileName" parameter denotes a single file.  In my case it's fileNmae="${longdate}.log".  In this case it wouldn't work.  However, for my app. I can change the name for the log file and this solution will work for me.  Plus 1 and I'll accept your answer.

Comment: how often are the files deleted, based on what, a day old, a month, file size?